# Batch File - If condition turns to an infinite loop

Tags: batch-file

I have the following if condition

```
if %dayNo% LSS 6 (
    set /a dayNo=%dayNo%+1 
    goto reStart
    )
*next code*
```

I'm expecting that if dayNo is already greater than 6, it would continue to *next code* but it goes back to reStart(which in turn goes back to this if condition even if dayNo is already greater than 6) thus creating an infinite loop.

Why is this happening and how should I fix this?

EDIT 2: **(CODE TO REPLICATE THE ERROR)**

I made a code to replicate the error. Assuming we have a "test" folder in Desktop with sub folders "day5" and "day6". I added a text file on day5 so the code should run correctly up until day 6 which will then keep on doing the goto syntax in the if statement and will loop the code till infinity. I use the pauses to check the code so feel free to remove the REM in them.

```
REM @echo off
REM setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set server= test
set /a dayNo=5

:reStart

set day=day%dayNo%
echo %day%

cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\
REM pause

    if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%server%\%day%\*.txt" then ( goto iterate )
    REM pause
    if exist "\tool\%server%\%day%" then (
    echo next code
    REM pause ) 

:iterate

if %dayNo% LSS 6 then (
    set /a dayNo=%dayNo%+1 
    REM pause
    goto reStart )

    echo This is the desired behavior and the code works!
```

Comment: Look into ["delayed expansion"](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html).

Comment: Show us some more of the code. Put an `Echo "%dayno%"` statement directly before the `if` line and report results. Please use the `edit` facility to modify your post to include this data.

Comment: @Magoo Edited the file

Comment: @Mofi I tried your suggestion but it still continues to loop. I also tried changing all %dayNo% to !dayNo! and enabling delayed expansion but the loop this continues

Comment: @Mofi sorry about that. I changed my terminologies and added a code that will replicate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There we few minor errors in this code.
I'll list them below. Before that as told by @Mofi (See his comment), understand the usage of IF by running IF /? in command prompt.

- I removed the extra space after "=" sign in "server= test"
- Removed "then" in IF statements as this usage is wrong.
- Added label ":iterate" to complete the code.

Check the modified code.

```
REM Following changes are done
REM removed an extra space before test "server= test"
REM removed "then" from IF.
REM proper line align done with ()
@echo off
REM setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set server=test
set /a dayNo=5

:reStart

set day=day%dayNo%
echo %day%

cd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\"
REM pause

    if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%server%\%day%\*.txt" ( goto iterate )
:iterate
    REM pause
    if exist "\tool\%server%\%day%" (
    echo next code
    REM pause 
    )


if %dayNo% LSS 6 (
    set /a dayNo=%dayNo%+1 
     pause
    goto reStart )

    echo This is the desired behavior and the code works!
```